# Oracle select with "in (multiple values)" does not use index

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, optimization

Oracle (12.1) does not use an index where it is really advantageous to do so.
A manuel query rewrite using `union all` helps but is really ugly.
Any ideas?

Schema:

- Table "umsatz", partitioned by each value of "monat" (= year + month as number).
- Simple non-unique index on (monat, kundengruppe).
- Statistics are available and up to date.
- "monat" is not very selective (a lot of values for each month), but column "kundengruppe" is quite selective for most of its values.
  "kundengruppe" has a hybrid histogram and the concrete used values here do *not* appear in the table (i.e. very selective) - changing them to seldom occuring values does not change anything. Querying for a single frequently occuring value leads to a full table/partition scan - which is okay in this case.

Query (reduced to the relevant, minimal part):

```
 SELECT SUM(u.umsatz_euro)
  FROM umsatz u
 WHERE u.monat BETWEEN 201701 AND 201712
   AND u.kundengruppe IN (123,456,987)
```

And the execution plan for it:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                        | Name                       | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                 |                            |    1 |    14 | 3074 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   SORT AGGREGATE                                 |                            |    1 |    14 |      |          |
|   2 |    MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT         |    1 |    14 | 3074 | 00:00:01 |
| * 3 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                             | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT_GRP_NUI |    1 |       | 3073 | 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 3 - access("UB"."MONAT">=201701 AND "UB"."MONAT"<=201712)
* 3 - filter("UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=123 OR "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=456 OR "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=987)
```

As you can see, only "monat" is used via access predicate (i.e. as index access), "kundengruppe" is used via filter.

.
If I change `WHERE` to a **simple `AND u.kundengruppe = 123`** the index is used for both values and the cost is reduced a lot (3000 -> 4):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                        | Name                       | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                 |                            |    1 |    14 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   SORT AGGREGATE                                 |                            |    1 |    14 |      |          |
|   2 |    MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT         |    1 |    14 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
| * 3 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                             | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT_GRP_NUI |    1 |       |    3 | 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 3 - access("UB"."MONAT">=201701 AND "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=123 AND "UB"."MONAT"<=201712)
* 3 - filter("UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=123)
```

.
I can **manually rewrite** the multiple-value-IN with a sematically equivalent **`UNION ALL`**:

```
SELECT SUM(u.umsatz_euro)
  FROM 
  (select * from umsatz u
    where u.kundengruppe = 123
   union all
   select * from umsatz u
    where u.kundengruppe = 456
   union all
   select * from umsatz u
    where u.kundengruppe = 987
  ) u
 WHERE u.monat BETWEEN 201701 AND 201712
```

The execution plan is using the index three times with cost *a lot* below the first plan (3000 -> 14), Oracle even pushed the "monat" predicate down into each select:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                          | Name                       | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                   |                            |    1 |    26 |   12 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   SORT AGGREGATE                                   |                            |    1 |    26 |      |          |
|   2 |    VIEW                                            |                            |    3 |    78 |   12 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |     UNION-ALL                                      |                            |      |       |      |          |
|   4 |      MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT         |    1 |    14 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
| * 5 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                             | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT_GRP_NUI |    1 |       |    3 | 00:00:01 |
|   6 |      MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT         |    1 |    14 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
| * 7 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                             | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT_GRP_NUI |    1 |       |    3 | 00:00:01 |
|   8 |      MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT         |    1 |    14 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
| * 9 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                             | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT_GRP_NUI |    1 |       |    3 | 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 5 - access("UB"."MONAT">=201701 AND "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=123 AND "UB"."MONAT"<=201712)
* 5 - filter("UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=123)
* 7 - access("UB"."MONAT">=201701 AND "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=456 AND "UB"."MONAT"<=201712)
* 7 - filter("UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=456)
* 9 - access("UB"."MONAT">=201701 AND "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=987 AND "UB"."MONAT"<=201712)
* 9 - filter("UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=987)
```

.
This is really cumbersome, especially if you have a List in Java and comfortably bind it via Hibernate to a single bind variable (`IN (:kgrpList)`).

The query hint `use_concat` does not help.
Any ideas to improve this situation?

---

**Another strange thing** in this situation:

If I use a bind variable for the number

```
 SELECT SUM(u.umsatz_euro)
  FROM umsatz u
 WHERE u.monat BETWEEN 201701 AND 201712
   AND u.kundengruppe = to_number(:a)    -- also for fixed  to_number('a123')
```

the plan uses a (slow) index skip scan:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                        | Name                       | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                 |                            |    1 |    14 |  955 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   SORT AGGREGATE                                 |                            |    1 |    14 |      |          |
|   2 |    MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT         | 1769 | 24766 |  955 | 00:00:01 |
| * 3 |     INDEX SKIP SCAN                              | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT_GRP_NUI | 1769 |       |   36 | 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 3 - access("UB"."MONAT">=201701 AND "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=TO_NUMBER(:A) AND "UB"."MONAT"<=201712)
* 3 - filter("UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=TO_NUMBER(:A))
```

Why the hell is Oracle doing this??

Comment: Have you run the gather statistics for the table recently?

Comment: what about the option to use INDEX hint ?

Comment: Statistics are up to date (see edited text). INDEX hint does not change anything, probalby because index is already used, but only for "monat" column.

Comment: can you use OEM ?

Comment: INDEX hint should force using the mentioned index instead of auto-selected.. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some tests based on ideas triggered by Conner's answer. The results answer my own question.

I changed the order of columns in the index to `(kundengruppe, monat)`, i.e. the selective column comes first ("monat" has only about 30 distinct values, but was put first because it is the partitioning attribute - a wrong thought for good access in this case).

Now the plan and cost look like expected:

```
SELECT SUM(u.umsatz_euro)
  FROM umsatz u
 WHERE u.monat BETWEEN 201701 AND 201712
   AND u.kundengruppe IN (123,456,987)
```

.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                         | Name                       | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                  |                            |    1 |    14 |    6 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   SORT AGGREGATE                                  |                            |    1 |    14 |      |          |
|   2 |    INLIST ITERATOR                                |                            |      |       |      |          |
|   3 |     MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT         |    1 |    14 |    6 | 00:00:01 |
| * 4 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                             | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT_GRP_NUI |    1 |       |    5 | 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 4 - access(("UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=123 OR "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=456 OR "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=987) AND "UB"."MONAT">=201701 AND "UB"."MONAT"<=201712)
```

.
Even when querying for more values which occur a bit more often, the index is used:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                         | Name                       | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                  |                            |    1 |    14 | 1518 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   SORT AGGREGATE                                  |                            |    1 |    14 |      |          |
|   2 |    INLIST ITERATOR                                |                            |      |       |      |          |
|   3 |     MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT         | 2664 | 37296 | 1518 | 00:00:01 |
| * 4 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                             | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT_GRP_NUI | 2900 |       |   12 | 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 4 - access(("UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=1899 OR "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=2032 OR "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=2160 OR "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=2165 OR "UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=5048) AND "UB"."MONAT">=201701 AND
  "UB"."MONAT"<=201712)
```

.
If I query for a (even single) "kundengruppe" which occurs often, Oracle selects an appropriate full table scan (well, *full mat_view scan* because the base table is a materialzed view):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name               | Rows   | Bytes   | Cost  | Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                    |      1 |      14 | 12494 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   SORT AGGREGATE            |                    |      1 |      14 |       |          |
|   2 |    PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR |                    | 117769 | 1648766 | 12494 | 00:00:01 |
| * 3 |     MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL    | UMSATZ_BUDGETBLATT | 117769 | 1648766 | 12494 | 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 3 - filter("UB"."KUNDENGRUPPE"=5047 AND "UB"."MONAT"<=201712)
```

.
This also answers the last part of my question - at least a bit:
When using a bind variable, Oracle does not know the concretely used value - it may be a value occurring frequently (but why an *index skip scan* instead of an *index range scan* for a known value?).
With the changed index column order an *index range scan* is used, even when querying for multiple bind variables.

**As overall, not really surprising result:

Column order in indexes matters - also when using partitioning!**

Answer (score 1):

A composite index is ultimately like all indexes, a key followed by data (the rowid).

So an index on (monat,kundengruppe ) will have keys in the ordered index structure conceptually like:

```
201701-123
201701-...
201701-...
201701-456
201701-...
201701-...
201701-987
201701-...
201701-...
201701-...
201701-...
201712-123
201712-...
201712-...
201712-456
201712-...
201712-...
201712-...
201712-987
201712-...
```

So keeping that in mind when it comes to queries:

```
WHERE u.monat BETWEEN 201701 AND 201712 AND u.kundengruppe = 123
```

I have a logical starting point (201701-123) and logical ending point (201702-123).

When we present the optimizer with something like:

```
WHERE u.monat BETWEEN 201701 AND 201712 AND u.kundengruppe in (123,456,789)
```

that is a tougher proposition to come up with an optimal index usage strategy.

*Ideally* it would be able to either sort the list in kundengruppe, and use an index access of - keys between with 201701-[min list value] and 201712-[max list value], or divide it up into 3 individual accesses as you have done in your manual rewrite.

But in both cases, that's a tough proposition in terms of *costing* such an access, ie, is it the *best* option to use, because (as per my index key listing), the number of values that might be interspersed *between* index keys of interest is tough to estimate.  Similarly, at which point do you abandon the strategy of the breaking an in-list into individual pieces.  What if the second predicate is:

```
u.kundengruppe in (123,456,... [500 more values]...789)
```

In that case, you probably do not want to split that out.

I don't have any great solutions for you sorry, but ultimately, there is only so much you can ask of the optimizer and (automatic) query transformation.